# Reading prepopulated SQLite database from Android Assets Folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a huge Database. And i want to save it in the Assets folder and read the data from it.

How i can do this?.
I read many answers but i didn't understand how to do it.

Please, Help me with the full steps. Because i am A beginner

Comment: Not work with me !! I tried but it's always make Errors !

Comment: Can you specify the errors?

Comment: I only want to know the full steps. 1 by 1. I want to know where to put these codes. And i want to connect My DatabaseHelper class to the File.sql that it's in the Assets folder

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. What you can ask is a specific question about your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Save your database in

> assets/databases/database_name.sqlite

Add this to your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

and sync your app.

Then Create database class:

**MyDatabase.java**

```
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name.sqlite";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public MyDatabase(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }
}
```

Then access your database like this where you want:

```
 MyDatabase myDatabase = new MyDatabase(context);
 SQLiteDatabase db = myDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: add : compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

to build.gradle(project: NAME) ??
or to
build.gradle(Module:app??)

Comment: Its giving me this error:

Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Comment: Add in **build.gradle(Module:app)** like this:


`dependencies {
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}`

Comment: ok, Now there is no any error. But, How i will select the data ?

txt.setText();

I want to show the data on the TextView.

Comment: `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
            
                Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                 
               if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 
                     do {

                                 // get your data here i.e
                                  String column1 = cursor.getString(0);
                                 
                            }

                        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

                    }`

Comment: Still have Errors. Can you connect to my PC via TeamViewer Please ?

Comment: here is the link for my new post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653230/selecting-data-from-sqlite-database-located-in-assets-folder